# How should I deal with the error "Error in monthdays() : Not monthly or quarterly data" from the forecast package?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm working with the FAO Price Index monthly data set and the forecast package to determine the price of FAO stock in December this year using time series plotting. For example, here is the graph I've developed so far.

[image]

Here is a slice of the data that I am using to produce this graph. From 1990-01-01 to 2006-08-01

```
dataslice = structure(list(ï..FAO.Monthly.Food.Price.Index = structure(c(7305, 
7336, 7364, 7395, 7425, 7456, 7486, 7517, 7548, 7578, 7609, 7639, 
7670, 7701, 7729, 7760, 7790, 7821, 7851, 7882, 7913, 7943, 7974, 
8004, 8035, 8066, 8095, 8126, 8156, 8187, 8217, 8248, 8279, 8309, 
8340, 8370, 8401, 8432, 8460, 8491, 8521, 8552, 8582, 8613, 8644, 
8674, 8705, 8735, 8766, 8797, 8825, 8856, 8886, 8917, 8947, 8978, 
9009, 9039, 9070, 9100, 9131, 9162, 9190, 9221, 9251, 9282, 9312, 
9343, 9374, 9404, 9435, 9465, 9496, 9527, 9556, 9587, 9617, 9648, 
9678, 9709, 9740, 9770, 9801, 9831, 9862, 9893, 9921, 9952, 9982, 
10013, 10043, 10074, 10105, 10135, 10166, 10196, 10227, 10258, 
10286, 10317, 10347, 10378, 10408, 10439, 10470, 10500, 10531, 
10561, 10592, 10623, 10651, 10682, 10712, 10743, 10773, 10804, 
10835, 10865, 10896, 10926, 10957, 10988, 11017, 11048, 11078, 
11109, 11139, 11170, 11201, 11231, 11262, 11292, 11323, 11354, 
11382, 11413, 11443, 11474, 11504, 11535, 11566, 11596, 11627, 
11657, 11688, 11719, 11747, 11778, 11808, 11839, 11869, 11900, 
11931, 11961, 11992, 12022, 12053, 12084, 12112, 12143, 12173, 
12204, 12234, 12265, 12296, 12326, 12357, 12387, 12418, 12449, 
12478, 12509, 12539, 12570, 12600, 12631, 12662, 12692, 12723, 
12753, 12784, 12815, 12843, 12874, 12904, 12935, 12965, 12996, 
13027, 13057, 13088, 13118, 13149, 13180, 13208, 13239, 13269, 
13300, 13330, 13361), class = "Date"), X = c(64.1, 64.4, 63.8, 
65.8, 64.4, 63.7, 62.5, 61.5, 61, 61.1, 61.9, 61.9, 60.8, 61.5, 
62, 60.7, 60.6, 61, 61.8, 61.4, 62.1, 64.3, 64.4, 64, 64.8, 65.7, 
66.1, 64.5, 64.8, 65.6, 64.4, 62.8, 63.5, 61.5, 62.4, 61, 61.3, 
61.2, 62.9, 62.5, 62, 61.5, 61.9, 60.5, 60.9, 61.2, 63, 64.3, 
64.5, 64.1, 64.5, 63.7, 65.6, 65.2, 63.9, 66.2, 69.3, 69.9, 73.2, 
73.1, 72.9, 74.4, 75.1, 74, 74, 75.1, 79.5, 78, 78.3, 80.4, 79.8, 
78, 77, 77.5, 78.6, 80.8, 82.4, 80.5, 80.2, 79.9, 76.9, 74.1, 
72.5, 71.4, 70.9, 71, 72.8, 73.4, 72.8, 70.2, 68.4, 69.8, 70, 
69.7, 70.3, 68, 67.4, 67.6, 67.4, 66.8, 66.4, 64.2, 64.3, 62.4, 
61.9, 62.7, 62.6, 62.1, 61, 58.4, 57, 55.8, 55.4, 54.6, 52.6, 
54.4, 54.6, 53.2, 53.2, 51.9, 52.6, 52.3, 52.8, 53.4, 53.6, 53.8, 
54, 53.2, 52.6, 53.4, 53.8, 54.4, 53.8, 54.2, 55.1, 54.6, 55.4, 
54.8, 56.5, 56.6, 55.4, 54.2, 54.7, 54.3, 53.5, 51.7, 52, 51, 
50.5, 51.3, 52, 53.4, 54.9, 55.2, 56.3, 55.6, 55.9, 56.5, 55.5, 
55.6, 56.3, 56, 56.7, 57.6, 58.7, 60.3, 61.8, 62.4, 64.3, 65, 
66.7, 67.2, 66.3, 66.1, 65.6, 64.5, 65.2, 64.7, 65.4, 65.6, 65.4, 
65.9, 67.1, 65.6, 66.3, 67.2, 67.4, 67.5, 68.4, 69.4, 68.8, 69.5, 
69.4, 70.4, 69.4, 69.7, 71, 71.1, 72.9, 72.9), X.1 = c("73.4", 
"76.0", "77.8", "80.4", "81.0", "83.1", "83.4", "83.7", "84.5", 
"85.4", "86.2", "83.7", "79.8", "81.7", "80.7", "79.5", "81.2", 
"80.4", "82.6", "79.4", "79.8", "82.3", "81.9", "78.3", "79.3", 
"80.9", "81.4", "77.4", "78.2", "78.0", "78.6", "77.5", "77.1", 
"73.5", "75.5", "72.8", "72.6", "72.1", "75.7", "74.8", "74.9", 
"77.6", "77.0", "73.8", "74.3", "73.5", "72.4", "70.1", "69.5", 
"70.9", "72.5", "72.9", "76.1", "74.4", "75.0", "76.6", "77.9", 
"78.1", "81.9", "78.2", "78.6", "83.1", "84.1", "84.9", "83.8", 
"81.0", "87.4", "87.1", "88.4", "88.8", "87.2", "81.2", "79.8", 
"79.9", "82.9", "80.8", "83.1", "83.5", "86.1", "88.8", "88.7", 
"85.9", "84.9", "81.0", "78.8", "78.7", "82.4", "83.5", "83.5", 
"80.0", "79.1", "80.1", "79.7", "75.5", "75.5", "69.5", "67.3", 
"68.3", "67.8", "67.8", "66.2", "66.2", "66.7", "64.2", "64.6", 
"64.1", "62.7", "63.3", "62.1", "62.8", "62.8", "61.1", "61.7", 
"62.1", "62.3", "64.0", "62.6", "60.0", "60.9", "58.9", "59.9", 
"60.2", "61.9", "61.3", "62.4", "61.7", "61.5", "59.2", "58.4", 
"58.6", "59.3", "59.3", "57.3", "60.9", "63.6", "64.1", "64.5", 
"62.5", "62.9", "63.0", "62.9", "61.3", "59.5", "58.2", "58.4", 
"56.6", "59.1", "56.3", "55.2", "55.4", "55.1", "55.0", "54.4", 
"52.6", "52.8", "51.1", "53.1", "54.1", "54.5", "55.7", "56.3", 
"56.2", "60.5", "60.7", "63.0", "62.7", "62.2", "61.2", "65.9", 
"63.8", "66.3", "66.3", "65.8", "68.8", "70.7", "68.9", "69.6", 
"67.7", "68.3", "68.6", "68.6", "70.0", "70.6", "69.3", "71.8", 
"73.0", "71.9", "72.3", "73.2", "73.3", "73.5", "73.6", "70.0", 
"67.7", "66.8", "66.2", "68.0", "70.4", "71.8", "74.2"), X.2 = c("53.5", 
"52.2", "41.4", "48.4", "39.2", "39.2", "39.2", "36.8", "38.1", 
"38.9", "39.4", "45.1", "46.9", "46.7", "45.8", "42.8", "42.1", 
"43.4", "40.4", "41.7", "45.4", "48.8", "50.8", "50.8", "52.9", 
"52.9", "52.4", "52.4", "54.6", "57.7", "58.1", "56.6", "58.1", 
"54.9", "53.8", "53.2", "53.3", "54.0", "53.3", "52.4", "51.7", 
"51.8", "49.7", "48.0", "45.1", "41.0", "41.2", "41.8", "45.5", 
"45.4", "46.0", "42.3", "42.3", "45.1", "45.6", "46.6", "49.9", 
"52.0", "53.2", "55.0", "58.9", "61.1", "61.8", "61.1", "61.2", 
"61.2", "64.6", "64.3", "64.3", "64.8", "64.8", "64.4", "64.3", 
"64.2", "63.0", "62.7", "61.0", "61.1", "61.3", "60.7", "60.1", 
"61.0", "59.9", "60.2", "60.3", "59.5", "59.3", "59.1", "58.8", 
"58.6", "58.1", "57.8", "59.0", "60.8", "61.0", "61.0", "60.9", 
"59.7", "57.8", "57.6", "56.5", "55.6", "55.3", "55.4", "53.9", 
"52.1", "52.1", "52.3", "52.4", "51.5", "50.7", "48.0", "47.4", 
"47.1", "46.4", "46.4", "46.8", "47.0", "47.5", "48.5", "50.2", 
"50.4", "50.1", "50.4", "50.9", "53.8", "55.6", "56.0", "57.4", 
"59.1", "59.6", "60.1", "59.7", "59.5", "59.7", "59.5", "62.0", 
"62.4", "62.9", "62.5", "62.1", "62.8", "60.6", "56.9", "53.0", 
"52.8", "50.7", "48.9", "44.8", "42.9", "40.6", "40.1", "41.6", 
"42.9", "45.5", "49.3", "51.3", "53.1", "53.7", "52.7", "52.6", 
"52.6", "53.2", "53.6", "55.2", "57.6", "58.6", "59.7", "60.9", 
"64.3", "65.2", "65.8", "67.8", "70.7", "72.6", "72.7", "73.3", 
"73.8", "75.1", "75.8", "76.2", "76.7", "77.0", "76.2", "76.5", 
"76.4", "77.1", "78.3", "78.7", "78.5", "78.0", "76.9", "74.3", 
"74.5", "73.1", "71.6", "71.3", "71.0", "71.3", "70.3"), X.3 = c("64.1", 
"62.2", "61.3", "62.8", "62.0", "60.7", "57.9", "55.7", "52.5", 
"52.8", "52.4", "52.6", "53.7", "55.2", "57.3", "57.6", "57.2", 
"56.5", "55.7", "58.3", "58.8", "60.6", "60.8", "62.7", "63.9", 
"66.5", "65.9", "63.0", "62.0", "61.8", "58.5", "56.1", "58.3", 
"58.2", "58.8", "58.5", "59.1", "58.1", "57.8", "57.3", "55.4", 
"52.8", "55.8", "56.6", "58.4", "61.4", "66.7", "68.9", "68.6", 
"66.8", "64.1", "62.4", "62.0", "60.1", "56.0", "57.5", "60.2", 
"61.7", "61.1", "62.7", "62.9", "62.5", "62.2", "62.7", "64.9", 
"69.1", "74.0", "72.6", "75.9", "80.2", "80.5", "82.7", "83.3", 
"85.7", "86.9", "95.3", "100.0", "94.3", "91.1", "85.8", "75.3", 
"71.1", "67.4", "67.6", "68.1", "68.4", "70.6", "70.8", "68.8", 
"65.2", "62.4", "65.7", "65.1", "65.6", "64.2", "63.4", "62.7", 
"62.7", "63.2", "60.8", "60.2", "59.0", "57.5", "54.1", "53.9", 
"57.7", "58.2", "56.8", "57.1", "54.9", "55.2", "53.7", "52.8", 
"53.6", "51.4", "53.0", "52.6", "51.5", "51.3", "50.4", "52.1", 
"52.2", "51.7", "51.8", "52.8", "51.4", "49.8", "48.6", "49.4", 
"51.2", "52.1", "53.7", "53.9", "53.0", "52.2", "51.0", "51.7", 
"51.0", "51.7", "51.6", "51.2", "51.0", "51.9", "52.0", "51.7", 
"50.4", "49.6", "49.3", "50.2", "52.0", "54.6", "58.1", "63.8", 
"64.4", "63.0", "59.8", "58.0", "57.8", "56.5", "56.4", "58.2", 
"57.7", "56.5", "59.9", "60.5", "60.6", "64.8", "65.7", "66.9", 
"67.5", "68.5", "70.2", "68.8", "66.4", "60.7", "59.1", "60.0", 
"59.3", "60.0", "60.5", "60.5", "60.3", "61.5", "59.5", "59.4", 
"60.2", "61.2", "60.9", "61.5", "62.1", "60.6", "61.5", "62.7", 
"64.8", "63.9", "65.1", "67.8", "67.8", "69.9", "69.6"), X.4 = c("44.6", 
"44.5", "45.7", "44.0", "45.5", "43.8", "43.7", "45.3", "44.8", 
"45.7", "48.3", "49.6", "49.4", "48.4", "48.7", "47.0", "46.5", 
"46.7", "48.2", "48.8", "48.6", "51.1", "51.8", "52.6", "52.8", 
"51.9", "54.1", "53.9", "54.0", "54.8", "51.9", "51.0", "52.2", 
"52.2", "53.8", "53.0", "53.9", "54.2", "53.0", "52.8", "51.9", 
"51.2", "53.2", "52.6", "52.5", "52.1", "56.2", "63.5", "63.8", 
"60.4", "61.3", "63.6", "67.7", "68.4", "67.1", "73.3", "80.5", 
"79.0", "88.3", "88.6", "82.6", "82.6", "84.4", "77.9", "76.8", 
"80.3", "83.9", "79.9", "76.3", "79.9", "79.0", "75.5", "70.7", 
"68.6", "68.1", "73.5", "73.3", "68.8", "66.0", "69.1", "71.4", 
"69.0", "70.0", "70.1", "70.7", "71.5", "70.3", "71.1", "71.6", 
"68.9", "65.5", "65.4", "67.9", "72.8", "76.7", "75.5", "79.2", 
"81.8", "84.6", "86.0", "89.9", "82.7", "83.5", "83.1", "84.5", 
"84.4", "84.3", "82.0", "77.3", "68.4", "62.3", "64.9", "62.2", 
"54.8", "48.6", "52.3", "54.0", "52.9", "51.3", "49.5", "48.6", 
"46.3", "47.8", "49.5", "44.5", "42.9", "42.6", "41.7", "38.4", 
"36.4", "37.7", "38.1", "37.3", "35.8", "38.2", "38.0", "36.5", 
"38.8", "47.4", "50.0", "45.4", "43.3", "48.2", "50.6", "49.2", 
"47.8", "47.6", "48.9", "51.6", "55.8", "56.1", "59.6", "56.7", 
"58.7", "63.9", "65.5", "64.3", "62.3", "59.2", "59.5", "61.0", 
"61.9", "58.8", "57.1", "59.3", "67.3", "68.8", "71.5", "71.2", 
"76.0", "76.7", "76.4", "73.5", "66.0", "64.8", "65.4", "66.2", 
"65.8", "66.9", "66.0", "63.1", "62.2", "66.7", "65.0", "64.2", 
"64.6", "64.4", "62.5", "64.0", "66.8", "65.4", "63.5", "63.6", 
"65.0", "65.1", "66.7", "68.3", "67.9", "70.4", "73.5"), X.5 = c("87.9", 
"90.7", "95.1", "94.3", "90.4", "80.3", "74.2", "67.6", "68.5", 
"60.8", "62.3", "60.3", "54.5", "52.7", "56.6", "52.7", "46.9", 
"56.9", "63.8", "58.5", "57.5", "56.4", "53.6", "55.7", "51.5", 
"48.5", "50.9", "58.5", "59.3", "64.1", "63.8", "60.8", "57.6", 
"53.9", "53.0", "50.4", "51.0", "53.0", "65.7", "69.0", "73.2", 
"64.3", "59.9", "57.8", "59.0", "63.7", "62.6", "65.1", "63.7", 
"67.0", "72.7", "68.1", "71.7", "74.6", "72.8", "74.9", "77.9", 
"78.9", "86.3", "90.8", "91.3", "89.2", "90.3", "84.8", "83.7", 
"86.8", "84.1", "80.3", "72.3", "73.3", "74.1", "76.2", "77.5", 
"79.3", "79.9", "74.1", "70.5", "75.3", "79.3", "76.6", "73.8", 
"68.8", "66.3", "66.5", "66.2", "66.9", "68.8", "69.9", "68.9", 
"70.7", "69.4", "72.4", "70.1", "70.6", "74.3", "76.3", "71.5", 
"66.3", "60.9", "60.0", "57.1", "50.1", "53.5", "52.5", "44.7", 
"46.2", "49.9", "50.0", "50.2", "42.2", "37.3", "33.5", "35.6", 
"37.3", "33.3", "35.6", "41.3", "41.9", "40.2", "37.2", "34.7", 
"32.7", "31.8", "37.3", "42.8", "51.8", "59.6", "64.6", "62.1", 
"66.5", "61.5", "62.0", "63.9", "61.1", "57.4", "54.1", "59.3", 
"56.0", "54.4", "50.2", "47.3", "42.0", "47.5", "48.5", "48.2", 
"40.5", "41.4", "42.6", "37.6", "35.6", "39.5", "39.0", "43.1", 
"46.5", "48.5", "49.2", "50.7", "55.7", "50.9", "48.0", "44.4", 
"41.6", "42.3", "42.3", "37.0", "36.9", "37.6", "38.9", "35.9", 
"36.2", "40.0", "40.7", "39.2", "42.9", "49.0", "46.9", "47.6", 
"52.3", "50.5", "51.0", "54.0", "56.3", "55.0", "53.2", "53.1", 
"56.0", "59.7", "61.5", "63.8", "68.8", "70.4", "82.6", "97.5", 
"111.1", "106.7", "108.2", "104.1", "95.3", "99.3", "83.2")), row.names = 4:203, class = "data.frame")
```

Then I made the graph using the code below.

```
tsall = ts(dataslice$X,frequency = 12/length(dataslice$X))

autoplot(tsall)+autolayer(meanf(tsall, h=120),series = "Mean", PI=FALSE)+
  autolayer(naive(tsall, h=120),
            series="Naïve", PI=FALSE) +
  autolayer(snaive(tsall, h=120),
            series="Seasonal naïve", PI=FALSE) +
  autolayer(rwf(tsall, drift=TRUE, h=120),
            series="Drift", PI=FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Forecasts for FAO Price Index December 2021")+
  xlab("Days")+
  ylab("Price Index")+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Forecast"))
```

The problem is that I am trying to smooth this data out using the monthdays() function to make a calendar adjustment because the days in each month are different and looking at the data and my example data in Forecasting: Principles and Practice, 3.2, I suspect this would make modeling easier.

```
tsall = (tsall/monthdays(tsall))

Error in monthdays(tsall) : Not monthly or quarterly data
```

Any assistance with this error code is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you dividing the frequency in the `ts` call by the length of your data.frame? If you just use frequency = 12, you tell `ts` it is monthtly data. After this you can use `monthdays`.

Comment: frequency 12 gives me roughly 18 months on the x axis, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is monthly and starts from 1990 Jan, hence your ts should be set up accordingly:

```
tsall = ts(dataslice$X, frequency = 12, start = c(1990,1))
```

Now this `tsall = (tsall/monthdays(stall))` part works just fine.

When you set `frequency = 12/length(dataslice$X) = 0.06`, the `monthdays` function will not work because your data is not monthly or quarterly as the description of the function suggests: 'Returns number of days in each month or quarter of the observed time period.'

For seasonal periods [see](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/)